# iOS dev: how to simulate app update in simulator or device?

Tags: ios, xcode

I need to fix a bug which happens when user updates the app while the app is put in background, how do I simulator the exact case in simulator or device?

I tried to install an old version, then build a new version, drag its IPA file from Organizer to the device but it prompted me to delete the existing app, I assume that real app update through AppStore does not delete existing app first, as user defaults are not removed after update.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Directly build and run app from xcode. And take app into background -> now install new version of app from xcode. This is exact situation what you want. (This is same in both device and simulator). This won't remove user defaults.

Comment: "now install new version of app from xcode" do you mean install from Organizer? And how do I install the build to simulator from XCode?

Comment: Just do a plain old debug build from Xcode after installing the old version from the App Store. Then you can actually debug the update process.

Comment: Then it will ask me to stop current running build, or did you mean run it then quit the app, run from simulator again then build and run from XCode?

Comment: Yes. quit the previous version of app -> Now Just open app from simulator -> Take it into background -> Build and run new version of app

Comment: It doesn't simulate exactly an update situation, for example database migration or NSUserDefault synchronization. You can do it with iTunes and ipa files though.